# animating an element's height using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some bars that are filled with a height %, but right when the page loads I would like all the bars to fill up and then decrease to 0.  I know how to fill it up with a for loop:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
```

but to have a it come back down

```
for(i = 100; i == 100; i--)
```

I'm just not sure how to put them together to make the variable i go to 100 then decrease back down to 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
for(i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
```

But you could just do this [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup):

```
$('someElement')
    .hide()
    .slideDown(500, function () {
        $(this).slideUp(500);
    });
```

The above would animate the element like you want. That code equates to roughly the following, in case you even want to do more complicated [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) animations:

```
$('someElement')
   .hide()
   .animate({ height: '100%' }, 500, function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: 0 }, 500);
    });
```

**Update:** Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhdRG/)** demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
    var height = (i <=100) ? i : 200 - i;
}
```

The variable `height` will go from 0 to 100 and then back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is what you are looking for. Result is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YuwYx/14/).

Answer (score 0):

the second one should be:

```
for(i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for(i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to animate the height of an object then I think you want the `.animate()` function of jQuery:

```
$('.bar-elements').animate({ height : '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $(this).animate({ height : 0 }, 1500);
});
```

or alternatively you can use the `slideUp`/`slideDown` functions that do this already:

```
$('.bar-elements').hide().slideDown(1500, function () {
    $(this).slideUp(1500);
});
```

Docs for `.animate()`: http://api.jquery.com/animate

Docs for `.slideUp()`: http://api.jquery.com/slideup

Answer (score 0):

dude slideToggle. Check it - http://jsfiddle.net/6hp2G/. works like a boss