# Jquery + CSS animation

Tags: jquery, css

Actually i wanted to slow the animation of increasing height and decreasing using jquery.I am using .css() to increasing and decrease height of a div.Pls help

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stickyfooter2").css({'height': '60px'});
    $('.stickyfooter2').mouseover(function(){
      $(".stickyfooter2").css({'height': '200px'});
    });
    $('.stickyfooter2').mouseleave(function(){
      $(".stickyfooter2").css({'height': '60px'});
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9038843/489560) on this exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution:

```
$('.stickyfooter2').mouseover(function(){
  $(".stickyfooter2").animate({'height': '200px'}, 2000);
});
$('.stickyfooter2').mouseleave(function(){
  $(".stickyfooter2").animate({'height': '60px'}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` or better still `slideToggle()` in which you can specify a speed:

```
$(".stickyfooter2").slideToggle('speed goes here in milliseconds');
```

If you want to ajust the height of the element us `.css()` along with slideToggle